# How can I change the value of initialValue after each run?

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop

**I want to change the value of initialValue after each run Ex: If I type 1000, this will give the output as 11,000 (10000 + 1,000), and I minus and I type 2000, this will give the output as 9,000 (11,000 - 2,000). Can somebody help me regarding to my problem.**

```js
function Compute(initialNum, numOne) {
this._initialNum = 10000;
this._numOne = numOne;

this.addNum = function() {
 this._initialNum = +this._initialNum + +this._numOne;
 return this._initialNum;
};

this.minusNum = function() {
 this._initialNum = +this._initialNum - +this._numOne;
 return this._initialNum;
};
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<input type="hidden" id="persistedResult" value="10000" /><br><br>
<input type="radio" id="rdoAdd" name="rdo">Add<br><br>
<input type="radio" id="rdoMinus" name="rdo">Minus<br><br>
<input type="text" id="txtNumOne"><br><br>
<button onclick="printResult()">Compute</button><br><br>

<table border="1px">
<th>Result</th>

<tbody id = "tblResult">

</tbody>
</table>
<script src="java.js"></script>
<script>

var tblResult = document.getElementById("tblResult");
var personList = [];

function printResult() {
        var display = "";
        var initialValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("persistedResult").value);
        //var objAccount = new Compute(initialValue, numOne);
        var rdoAdd = document.getElementById("rdoAdd");
        var rdoMinus = document.getElementById("rdoMinus");
        var numOne = parseInt(document.getElementById('txtNumOne').value);
        //var numTwo = parseInt(document.getElementById('txtNumTwo').value);
        var objCompute = new Compute(initialValue, numOne);
        personList.push(objCompute);

        console.log(personList);
        var newValue = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < personList.length; i++) {
            if(rdoAdd.checked) {
                //display += objAccount.addNum(); 
                newValue = personList[i].addNum();
                display = "<tr>";
                display += "<td>" + (newValue) + "</td>";
                display += "<tr>";
                tblResult.innerHTML += display;
            resetx();

            } else if(rdoMinus.checked){
                //display += objAccount.minusNum();
                newValue = personList[i]. minusNum();
                display = "<tr>";
                display += "<td>" + (newValue) + "</td>"; 
                display += "<tr>";
                tblResult.innerHTML += display;
            resetx();
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("persistedResult").value = newValue;
}
 function resetx() {
  document.getElementById('txtNumOne').value = "";
  document.getElementById("rdoAdd").checked = false;
  document.getElementById("rdoMinus").checked = false;
 }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**I want to change the value of initialValue after each run Ex: If I type 1000, this will give the output as 11,000 (10000 + 1,000), and I minus and I type 2000, this will give the output as 9,000 (11,000 - 2,000). Can somebody help me regarding to my problem.**

```js
//constructor function
function Compute(initialNum, numOne) {
this._initialNum = 10000;
this._numOne = numOne;

this.addNum = function() {
 this._initialNum = +this._initialNum + +this._numOne;
 return this._initialNum;
};

this.minusNum = function() {
 this._initialNum = +this._initialNum - +this._numOne;
 return this._initialNum;
};
}

//javascript in the body tag
var tblResult = document.getElementById("tblResult");
var personList = [];

function printResult() {
        var display = "";
        var initialValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("persistedResult").value);
        var rdoAdd = document.getElementById("rdoAdd");
        var rdoMinus = document.getElementById("rdoMinus");
        var numOne = parseInt(document.getElementById('txtNumOne').value);
        var objCompute = new Compute(initialValue, numOne);
        personList.push(objCompute);

        console.log(personList);
        var newValue = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < personList.length; i++) {
            if(rdoAdd.checked) {
                newValue = personList[i].addNum();
                display = "<tr>";
                display += "<td>" + (newValue) + "</td>";
                display += "<tr>";
                tblResult.innerHTML += display;
            resetx();

            } else if(rdoMinus.checked){
                newValue = personList[i]. minusNum();
                display = "<tr>";
                display += "<td>" + (newValue) + "</td>"; 
                display += "<tr>";
                tblResult.innerHTML += display;
            resetx();
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("persistedResult").value = newValue;
}
 function resetx() {
  document.getElementById('txtNumOne').value = "";
  document.getElementById("rdoAdd").checked = false;
  document.getElementById("rdoMinus").checked = false;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<input type="hidden" id="persistedResult" value="10000" /><br><br>
<input type="radio" id="rdoAdd" name="rdo">Add<br><br> //rdo for Add
<input type="radio" id="rdoMinus" name="rdo">Minus<br><br> //rdo for Subs
<input type="text" id="txtNumOne"><br><br> 
<button onclick="printResult()">Compute</button><br><br>

<table border="1px">
<th>Result</th>

<tbody id = "tblResult">

</tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

**I want to change the value of initialValue after each run Ex: If I type 1000, this will give the output as 11,000 (10000 + 1,000), and I minus and I type 2000, this will give the output as 9,000 (11,000 - 2,000). Can somebody help me regarding to my problem.**

```
function printResult() {
        var display = "";
        var initialValue = 10000;
        //var objAccount = new Compute(initialValue, numOne);
        var rdoAdd = document.getElementById("rdoAdd");
        var rdoMinus = document.getElementById("rdoMinus");
        var numOne = parseInt(document.getElementById('txtNumOne').value);
        //var numTwo = parseInt(document.getElementById('txtNumTwo').value);
        var objCompute = new Compute(initialValue, numOne);
        personList.push(objCompute);

        console.log(personList);

        for(var i = 0; i < personList.length; i++) {
            if(rdoAdd.checked) {
                //display += objAccount.addNum(); 
                display = "<tr>";
                display += "<td>" + (personList[i].addNum()) + "</td>";
                display += "<tr>";
                tblResult.innerHTML += display;
            resetx();

            } else if(rdoMinus.checked){
                //display += objAccount.minusNum();
                display = "<tr>";
                display += "<td>" + (personList[i].minusNum()) + "</td>"; 
                display += "<tr>";
                tblResult.innerHTML += display;
            resetx();
        }
    }
}

//Constructor Function
function Compute(initialNum, numOne) {
this._initialNum = initialNum;
this._numOne = numOne;


this.addNum = function() {
    this._initialNum += this._numOne;
    return this._initialNum;
};

this.minusNum = function() {
    this._initialNum -= this._numOne;
    return this._initialNum;
};
}
```

Comment: Please clarify.  Can you show some examples.  What do you expect and what are you getting?

Comment: I have a initial value of 10,000 and I have 2 radio buttons one is for add and one is for minus and also one textbox. When I choose the radio button for add. I want to add something to initial value for example (10,000 + 1,000). The initial Value will become 11,000 and I want to choose the minus radio button and i want to subsctract it to 2,000 the answer will be 9,000(11,000 - 2,000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since HTTP is stateless and you want to perform operations on 2 different actions, you will need to store the result of each action in some place. For the simplest example, you can create hidden field on your HTML page. This can have value of 10000 when your HTML is loaded for the first time and update it’s value after each action is executed.

Let’s assume you have following hidden field on your HTML:

```
<input type=“hidden” id=“persistedResult” value=“10000” />
```

Here is your updated `printResult` method:

```
function printResult() {
        var display = "";
        var initialValue = parseInt(document.getElementById(‘persistedResult’).value);
        //var objAccount = new Compute(initialValue, numOne);
        var rdoAdd = document.getElementById("rdoAdd");
        var rdoMinus = document.getElementById("rdoMinus");
        var numOne = parseInt(document.getElementById('txtNumOne').value);
        //var numTwo = parseInt(document.getElementById('txtNumTwo').value);
        var objCompute = new Compute(initialValue, numOne);
        personList.push(objCompute);

        console.log(personList);
        var newValue = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < personList.length; i++) {
            if(rdoAdd.checked) {
                //display += objAccount.addNum(); 
                newValue = personList[i].addNum();
                display = "<tr>";
                display += "<td>" + (newValue) + "</td>";
                display += "<tr>";
                tblResult.innerHTML += display;
            resetx();

            } else if(rdoMinus.checked){
                //display += objAccount.minusNum();
                newValue = personList[i]. minusNum();
                display = "<tr>";
                display += "<td>" + (newValue) + "</td>"; 
                display += "<tr>";
                tblResult.innerHTML += display;
            resetx();
        }
    }
    document.getElementById(‘persistedResult’).value = newValue;
}
```

> **Note:** This is a primitive example to guide you how to achieve data persistence. Generally, the data will be persisted on server.
>
> This code takes care of scenario where there is only one person in the list, which is the approach in your current code example. You will need to enhance the logic if you want to have this working on an array of persons.

Comment: when I type 2 digit numbers for example 10 (10000 + 10 = 10010) and when I subsctract it (10010 - 10 = 10000) the result is fine but the problem is when I type 3 digit numbers for example (10000 + 100 = 10010)  and I substract again with 100 the result is 10000. What do you think sir?

Comment: @SwimmingPool, can you add your code on https://jsfiddle.net so that I can verify?

Comment: Did you see my codes on the link above sorry I really don't know how to used jsfiddle. I edit the this threads

Comment: @SwimmingPool, I will need sometime before I can check it. Will post my finding as early as possible.

Comment: Correcting the comment as the previous one had typo and I am unable to edit it. No change in code or result. --> 

It's now working. You can check result here now: jsfiddle.net/nc3ob028/17 Basically, you were setting "10000" instead of "initialNum" in your constructor: function Compute(initialNum, numOne) { this._initialNum = 10000; .... }

Answer (score 0):

```
  var valueEl = document.getElementById('value');
  var addEl = document.getElementById('add');
  var resultEl = document.getElementById('result');
  var calculateEl = document.getElementById('calculate');
  var initialValue = 1000;

  function appendResult(result) {
    var liEl = document.createElement("li");
    liEl.innerHTML = result;
        resultEl.appendChild(liEl);     
  }

  function handleClickCalculate() {
    var operand = addEl.checked ? 1 : -1;
    var value = +valueEl.value * operand;
    initialValue += value
    appendResult(initialValue);
  }

  calculateEl.addEventListener('click', handleClickCalculate)
  appendResult(initialValue);
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afrievalt/98e6d0sj/)

Comment: how about my constructor function? where is the property or methods?

Comment: What about it?  You don't need it, it doesn't impact initialValue.  Does this answer your question?  If so, please mark as complete.  If you have a different question, please add another question.  Did you click the jsFiddle link?